# How to check if TextView contains a string from my String array?

Tags: android, string

I have an array containing strings. This is like:

```
String[] stops = {
        "Bangalore International Exhibition Center", "Jindal", "Manjunathnagar", "Nagasandra", "Dasarahalli", "Jalahalli", "Peenya Industry", "Peenya", "Yeswanthpur Industry", "Yeswanthpur", "Sandal Soap Factory", "Mahalaxmi", "Rajajinagar", "Kuvempu Road", "Srirampura", "Sampige Road", "Kempegowda Interchange", "Chikpet", "K R Market", "National College", "Lalbagh", "South End Circle", "Jayanagar", "R V Road Interchange", "Banashankari", "J P Nagar", "Puttenahalli", "Anjanapura Cross Road", "Krishna Leela Park", "Vajrahalli", "Thaighattapura", "Anjanapura/NICE Junction", "Kengeri", "R V College of Engineering", "Bangalore University Cross", "Rajarajeshwari Nagar", "Nayandahalli", "Mysore Road", "Deepanjali Nagar", "Attiguppe", "Vijayanagar", "Hosahall1i", "Magadi Road", "Sir M Vishweshwariah", "Vidhana Soudha", "M G Road Interchange", "Trinity", "Halasuru", "Indiranagar", "S V Road", "Baiyyappanahalli", "Jyotipura", "K R Puram", "Mahadevpura", "Garudacharpalya", "Doddanekkundi Induatrial State", "Vishweshwariah Industrial State", "Kundanahalli", "Vydhehi Hospital", "Satya Sai Medical Institute", "ITPB", "Kadugodi Industrial Area", "Ujjwal Vidhyalaya", "Whitefield", "Nagawara", "Arabic College", "Venkateshpura", "Tannery Town", "Pottery Town", "Cantonment Railway Station", "Shivajinagar", "Vellara Junction", "Langford Town", "Mico Bosch", "Dairy Circle", "Swagath Road Cross", "Jayadeva Hospital Interchange", "J P Nagar 4th Phase", "IIMB", "Hulimavu", "Gottigere", "Ragigudda Temple", "BTM Layout", "Silk Board", "HSR Layout", "Oxford College", "Muneshwara Nagar", "Chikkabegur", "Basapura Road", "Hosa Road", "Electronics City 1", "Electronics City 2", "Huskur Road", "Hebbagodi", "Bommasandra"
        };
```

Now I have a TextView. I want to know, how can I check if the value entered by the user in my TextView is from that string array or not. And if not, it should prompt the user for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(check(textView.getText.toString())){
//do somethingif true
}else{
//else
}

public boolean check(String text){
    for(String s: stops){
    if(s.equalsIngoreCase(text)){
    return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function like this to check the input is there in your string array, if it return false, ask the user for correction else do what ever you want.

```
  public boolean check(String input){
    for(String s: stops){
    if(s.equalsIngoreCase(input)){
    return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

use this like [AlertDialog](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog) to see how alert is done in android

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String s = obj_tv.getText().toString();

   String[] stops = {
        "Bangalore International Exhibition Center", "Jindal", "Manjunathnagar", "Nagasandra", "Dasarahalli", "Jalahalli", "Peenya Industry", "Peenya", "Yeswanthpur Industry", "Yeswanthpur", "Sandal Soap Factory", "Mahalaxmi", "Rajajinagar", "Kuvempu Road", "Srirampura", "Sampige Road", "Kempegowda Interchange", "Chikpet", "K R Market", "National College", "Lalbagh", "South End Circle", "Jayanagar", "R V Road Interchange", "Banashankari", "J P Nagar", "Puttenahalli", "Anjanapura Cross Road", "Krishna Leela Park", "Vajrahalli", "Thaighattapura", "Anjanapura/NICE Junction", "Kengeri", "R V College of Engineering", "Bangalore University Cross", "Rajarajeshwari Nagar", "Nayandahalli", "Mysore Road", "Deepanjali Nagar", "Attiguppe", "Vijayanagar", "Hosahall1i", "Magadi Road", "Sir M Vishweshwariah", "Vidhana Soudha", "M G Road Interchange", "Trinity", "Halasuru", "Indiranagar", "S V Road", "Baiyyappanahalli", "Jyotipura", "K R Puram", "Mahadevpura", "Garudacharpalya", "Doddanekkundi Induatrial State", "Vishweshwariah Industrial State", "Kundanahalli", "Vydhehi Hospital", "Satya Sai Medical Institute", "ITPB", "Kadugodi Industrial Area", "Ujjwal Vidhyalaya", "Whitefield", "Nagawara", "Arabic College", "Venkateshpura", "Tannery Town", "Pottery Town", "Cantonment Railway Station", "Shivajinagar", "Vellara Junction", "Langford Town", "Mico Bosch", "Dairy Circle", "Swagath Road Cross", "Jayadeva Hospital Interchange", "J P Nagar 4th Phase", "IIMB", "Hulimavu", "Gottigere", "Ragigudda Temple", "BTM Layout", "Silk Board", "HSR Layout", "Oxford College", "Muneshwara Nagar", "Chikkabegur", "Basapura Road", "Hosa Road", "Electronics City 1", "Electronics City 2", "Huskur Road", "Hebbagodi", "Bommasandra"
        };

    for(int i = 0; i < stops.length; i++)
    {
       if(stops[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s))
       {
        // do something 
       }
       else
       {
         // do something 
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean checkavailability(String input)
{
for(String s: stops){
if(s.equalsIngoreCase(input))
{
return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
```

Use this.